# Getting value from session if available, if not, take from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

This method is a constructor that has to decide which URL to add to the response header as Allow-Origin. i am actually adding the Allow-Origin later according to the value of PermittedOrigion variable. I am using Session to eliminate database access.

Could i write it more efficient?  I am working with asp.net webform

```
public ResponseAsJson(HttpRequest request, int affiliateId)
    {
        string cacheKeyName = $"PermittedOrigion_{affiliateId.ToString()}";
        const string notDefined = "N";
        object ValueFromCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKeyName];

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ValueFromCache?.ToString()))
        {
            if (ValueFromCache.ToString() == notDefined)
                return;

            PermittedOrigion = ValueFromCache.ToString();
            return;
        }

        string actualOrigion = null;

        if (request.UrlReferrer != null)
           actualOrigion = request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

        string[] strFromDB = RM.BL.Affiliate.Instance(affiliateId).LUAffiliate.AccessControlAllowOriginJsonResult.Split(';');

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actualOrigion) && strFromDB.Contains(actualOrigion))
        {
            PermittedOrigion = actualOrigion;
        }
        else 
        {
            string strLocalhost = strFromDB.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("http://localhost")).FirstOrDefault();

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLocalhost))
                PermittedOrigion = strLocalhost;
        }

        if (PermittedOrigion == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKeyName] = notDefined;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKeyName] = PermittedOrigion;
        }           


    }
```

Comment: Could you add a couple of tags about the technologies you used? Like [tag:asp.net] or [tag:asp.net-core], [tag:entity-framework] etc?

Answer (score 1):

Some recommendations:

1) Give your method a better name. `ResponseAsJson` is not what it does. Proposal: `AppendAllowOriginHeader`

2) Your method relies on the `affiliateId` inputparameter. I would change the parameter to `int? affiliateId` and then add a short guard:

```
if(!affiliateId.HasValue) {
   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(affiliateId)); 
}
```

Also keep in mind, that the id may be invalid in which I would prefere to throw an `InvalidArgumentException`

3) Let's clean up: Extract the method in two subfunctions:`TryAddFromCache(string key)` and `TryAddFromAllowedOrigins`

TryAddFromCache could look like:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)) {
   return false;
}   

...
return true;
```

And in AppendAllowOriginHeader:

```
if (TryAddFromCache()) {
    return;
}
```

4) As a rule: Use const or var wherever possible.

5) Extract a second method:

`bool TryAddFromAllowedOrigins(IEnumerable<string> allowedOrigins) { ... }`

6) Performance: In this case we have the database access as bottleneck.
The party starts at:

```
RM.BL.Affiliate.Instance(affiliateId).LUAffiliate.AccessControlAllowOriginJsonResult.Split(';');
```

.. which has the most impact.

Your array `strFromDB` will probably not hold references to several thousand strings. So filtering or sorting (which should be the work of the db anyway) has no impact.

```
 string strLocalhost = strFromDB.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("http://localhost")).FirstOrDefault();
```

can be changed to:

```
strFromDB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("..."));
```

7) Consider using better names: for example `strFromDB` could be changed to `allowedOrigins`